# How to decode URL with BeanShell?

Tags: regex, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

I need to pass a parameter (part of URL) in a request  for example:

```
"S;4;163;1;O;rAghjgjU="
```

But this value is extracted as a regular expression like that:

```
"S%3B4%3B163%3B1%3BO%3BrAghjgjU%3D"
```

I want to use BeanShell to decode the URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. JMeter provides [__urldecode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) function so if you use it like:

   ```
   ${__urldecode(S%3B4%3B163%3B1%3BO%3BrAghjgjU%3D)}
   ```

   you'll get the required value.
2. If you still want to go for Beanshell, you can invoke [URLDecoder.decode();](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String)) method like:

   ```
   String decoded = URLDecoder.decode("S%3B4%3B163%3B1%3BO%3BrAghjgjU%3D", "UTF-8");
   ```
3. There is also [__Beanshell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function which allows executing arbitrary Beanshell script, invoke it like:

   ```
   ${__BeanShell(URLDecoder.decode("S%3B4%3B163%3B1%3BO%3BrAghjgjU%3D"\, "UTF-8"),)}
   ```

   See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter, in particular pay attention to how Java and JMeter API classes are invoked from within Beanshell scripts.